# Alfresco and Google chart

Tags: graph, charts, alfresco, alfresco-share

I use alfresco 5.2 and I install google graphs using instruction

https://code.google.com/archive/p/statistics-and-graphs/downloads

First I add in alfresco-global.properties

```
## AUDIT
audit.enabled=true
audit.alfresco-access.enabled=true
```

than

1. - Put the provided AMP, 'Statistics.amp', into /amps_share .
2. - Run /apply_amps
3. - Restart Alfresco

I got in admin console statistics&graphs and when clik on statistics&graphs i got error

[image]

```
The Web Script /share/service/extras/components/console/statistics has    responded with a status of 500 - Internal Error.

500 Description:    An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Message:    01180016 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/site-webscripts/com/devcom/components/console/statistics.get.js': 01180015 ReferenceError: "response" is not defined. (file:/C:/alfresco-community/tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/com/devcom/components/console/statistics.get.js#2104)
Server: Spring WebScripts - v6.11.0 schema 1.000
Time:   18.02.2017. 23.30.54

Diagnostics:    Inspect Web Script (com/devcom/components/console/statistics.get)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install it in my local Alfresco too. But this module is quite old, and don't seem to be maintained anymore. I had to do minor changes to be able to see something:

- In the file `Statistics_project/config/alfresco/site-webscripts/com/devcom/components/console/statistics.get.js`:

  - Line 5 and 147: I deleted the variable `site`
  - Line 6: In the URL, I removed the parameter `&limit=0`

Then, I was able to open the page. But I had an error message. I had to change the file `Statistics_project/source/web/scripts/statistics.js`:

- Line 114: In the URL, I removed the parameter `&limit=0`.

Then I was able to open the page, and select a site but nothing is displayed:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy9J6.png)

I recommend you to look at this plugin:
https://addons.alfresco.com/addons/alfresco-audit-analysis-and-reporting-aaar